# Submitting information from one servlet to another

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I have a little bug that I hope someone can solve for me.

**servlet1:**

The story here is simple - I created a form and inside it an image. When you click this image information should be submitted to servlet2.

```
public void f1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  
IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html></br>");
    out.print("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'   
    src='functions.js'></script></br>");
    out.print("<body></br>");
    out.print("<form method='post' name='mainForm' action='servlet2'><br/>");
    out.print("<img id='someId' src='someSrc' onclick='submit()'/><br/>");
    out.print("<label id='gameStatus'>Welcome!</label></br>");        
    out.print("</form></br>");
    out.print("</body>\n</html></br>");
}
```

OK, I clicked the image and information is now submitted (I suppose)

**servlet2:**

Here I would just like to print out the parameters submitted earlier.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();        
    Enumeration parameters = request.getParameterNames();        
    while (parameters.hasMoreElements())
    {            
        out.print((String)parameters.nextElement() + "<br/>");                
    }
}
```

unf. my output is null so i guess information was not submitted. The question is why? any typos? or a logical prob?
Thank you!

Comment: All of those `<br/>` tags are pointless, and `</br>` is invalid. Find and read some tutorials on HTML basics. Using `out.print(...)` to output HTML from a servlet is very 1990's -- find and read some tutorials on JSP basics.

Comment: according to me, dont you need multipart form to upload / share an image to server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information you are trying to pass? I don't see any input field in your form.

Kindly try to add input in your form. Let us see if it is displayed in your second servlet.

```
out.print("<form method='post' name='mainForm' action='servlet2'><br/>");
out.print("<input type='text' name='param1' value='test' /><br/>");
out.print("<img id='someId' src='someSrc' onclick='submit()'/><br/>");
out.print("<label id='gameStatus'>Welcome!</label></br>");
```

Check if param1 is displayed.

Comment: Yes it is displayed. I guess my err is pretty basic as i have to mark any information i want to submit with <input> tag. i thoght i can retrieve image id just like that - i guess i was wrong:) thank you!

Comment: but... there is another bug. with input type='text' everything works, just like you did with param1. but with input type='image' - nothing is shown after submit. strange - any ideas?

Comment: what data you are trying to pass?

Comment: i just want to retrieve the name/id tags of all the inputs inside this form. the images are representing game cards. i want to get the clicked card's name/id in order to determine which was chosen etc.. using rquest.getparameter(cardName)

Comment: have you put a `name` attribute in your image?

Comment: `<img id='someId' name='someName' src='someSrc' onclick='submit()'/>`

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't think any data is sent if it's not inside input tags.